# Kendo widgets does not work when CSP is enabled

Tags: security, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, content-security-policy

I have ASP.NET Core application and i am using Telerik's UI for ASP.NET Core framework for certain widgets like Date, DropDownList, Charts etc.

Application is loading all javascripts, images, css from its own server. So i have enabled CSP policy as below

```
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval';   
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';    
img-src 'self' data:;    
font-src 'self';    
media-src 'none';    
object-src 'none';   
child-src https://xxxx.yyyy.com;   
report-uri http://myapplication/csp/report;
```

However when the page load i see error in chrome's console

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'".
>   Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-oii70XYoqukWS9204nbwatxgYOYcr06+rftc4egdfUk='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution

this error is repeated for several Kendo widgets that i'm using on that page. For example date widget. In cshtml i have configured date as below

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
.Name("sbDate")
.HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "mydate" }))
```

which gets render in html as

```
<input class="mydate" id="sbDate" name="sbDate" type="date" value="" /><script>jQuery(function(){jQuery("#sbDate").kendoDatePicker({"format":"M/d/yyyy","footer":false});});</script>
```

I have already gone through Telerik's suggestion [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/troubleshoot/content-security-policy) and [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/'unsafe-eval'-support-in-content-security-policy) for CSP. And as per the suggestion i only i have to add `unsafe-eval` to get widgets working. However looks like that is not true. I also have to add `unsafe-inline` to get widgets working.

But the whole point of enabling CSP is to not allow inline scripts.

**Questions**
Is there any way to solve this issue?

**Update 1**
Widgets only works in IE 11 without adding `unsafe-inline`. In chrome and IE edge widget requires `unsafe-inline` to work.

Answer (score 1):

The solution below might work (i have not tried yet)

1> Add `Deferred` method for each kendo widget. Like

```
    @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("BeginDate").Deferred())
```

2> In each view that is using Kendo control, at the bottom add the script tag

```
  <script asp-add-nonce="true">
      @Html.Kendo().DeferredScripts(false)
  </script>
```

Note that `asp-add-nonce` is not out of the box from asp.core. You have to install [Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders) nuget library. I found [this article](https://joonasw.net/view/csp-in-aspnet-core) from the author that shows how to configure CSP for .net core application and also how to generate new nonce for each request.

3>Dont configure CSP policy in web.config because we need different nonce value for each request, instead configure the CSP policy using [Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders) middleware as mentioned in the article.

4>I thinks we don't need to add `unsafe-inline` if we use random `nonce` (unless you are targeting to older browsers)

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell if this would solve your issue, but in our Application, we are using the [Deferring](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/fundamentals#configuration-Deferring) feature, but for other reasons. Our reason is that we load all scripts (esp. `jquery.js`) at the end of the page. But the side effect is that no `jQuery` script calls are rendered into the page anymore. You can control the place to generate all scripts by executing `@Html.Kendo().DeferredScripts()` (but you will find more help in the docs above). Anyway, probably in the context of CSP, even that `<script>` block at the very end of the page is still considered "inline". But give it a try.

Comment: Thanks. I found SO post here even differed would not work because scripts are kept in the view. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39125743/how-can-i-get-kendoui-mvc-to-work-with-content-security-policy However we can differedscripts all at once inside script tag and can use `nonce` on script tag for CSP.