# Chrome Extension CSP - unsafe-eval and unsafe-inline in 3rd party js library and stylesheet

Tags: google-chrome-extension, kendo-grid, content-security-policy

Browser - Chrome Version 85.0.4183.102

There are lot of threads around this topic but I could not find what is the safest and correct way to deal with 3rd party libraries.
I am using kendo grid (jQuery) in my chrome extension.. it has "unsafe-eval" and "unsafe-inline"... unless I set the below entry in manifest.json its not working.

```
"content_security_policy": "font-src data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self';"
```

Since its not safest practice.. how can I bypass this with hash or nonce.

Note: The Kendo library is downloaded and referred from local machine. (No CDN references)

**'unsafe-line'**

When I remove 'unsafe-inline' as expected its giving out 5 errors in my case and providing 5 different sha-256 hashes. I replaced 'unsafe-inline' with 5 hashes but still getting the same error.

Below is the error when I tried only with 1 hash.

Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'sha256-lzhPGNqxpwmBda/ftMrdga7dSTDWPq2rpjz66R6TVFw='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-lzhPGNqxpwmBda/ftMrdga7dSTDWPq2rpjz66R6TVFw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

**'unsafe-eval'**

When I remove 'unsafe-eval' as expected giving out errors with no generated hash to replace.

**'font-src data:'**

yet to attempt to bypass.

I even tried nonce but did not work.

am I missing something? or do I need to live with 'unsafe-inline' and 'unsafe-eval'. If yes, what is the potential risk? I am planning to release this extension to public.

EDIT: I tried sandbox as suggested below.

Here is what I did.

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/iframe.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="iframe" src="sandbox.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

sandbox.html has kendo reference `<script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>`

Here is the manifest.json change

```
"sandbox": {
"pages:": [
  "sandbox.html"
]},"content_security_policy": "sandbox allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups;"
```

I am still getting errors with kendo. Any suggestions?

Comment: Assuming you can't get rid of those evals, the only safe way in the puristic sense would be to use the library inside a [sandbox](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval).

Comment: Thanks for sandbox suggestion. I tried but still getting errors.. please see EDIT section above.

Comment: See the [example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#sandboxed-frame) linked in the documentation, it doesn't modify CSP.

Comment: It doesn't matter I add or not CSP directive. its not working.

Comment: Well, start with that demo extension and add your files there, see if it works, then adapt it to your main extension.

Comment: I tried kendo with demo extension. Its working... The only difference with my manifest is in demo "eventpage.html" is defined as background page but I have scripts in background (background.js). I cannot add my index.html to background since "page" and "scripts" cannot be added at the same time. I think we are very close. Any more advises?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221837/discussion-between-san-and-woxxom).

Answer (score 2):

**'unsafe-inline' in scripts and styles**

Chrome unintentionally misleads you with [hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63934589/csp-header-fails-with-refused-to-apply-inline-style-but-i-have-already-adde/63974460#63974460) for inline styles. The same is with hashes for inline scripts:

1. `<script>...</script>` consiedres as inline and can be allowed with *'nonce-value'* or/and *'hash-value'* tokens.
2. `<tag onEvent='event_handler_script'>` and `<a href='javascript:click_handler_script'>` both considers as inlnie script but cannot be allowed by *'nonce-value'* or/and *'hash-value'* tokens. But Chrome calculates sha256 for them, because it prepares to implement ['unsafe-hashes'](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#unsafe-hashes-usage) token (spec section is not normative <s>so implementation is delayed</s> support [is implemented](http://csplite.com/csp/test173/) already).

Therefore is case (1) you could easily ged rid of 'unsafe-inline', in case (2) - you need to modify code first.

**'unsafe-eval' in scripts**

Content Security Policy spec does not provide way to allow unsafe scripts constructions via 'nonce/hash' tokens. Changes of the script code will be required, in some cases - purely "cosmetic".

CSP considers as [eval-constructs](https://csplite.com/csp148/):

- eval()
- setTimeout('string')
- setInterval('string')
- Function()
- setImmediate()
- execScript()

Note that setTimeout()/setInterval() are "eval" only when callback function passed as a string. If callback is an anonymous funct or "function by name" - those **not fall** under eval.
In this case, you can easily get rid of eval without changing the logic of the script.

Comment: There is no issue with my code.. its all with 3rd party Kendo script so it can't be changed. What is the solution here?

Comment: There is a solition how to get rid of 'unsafe-inline' in script for Kendo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39125743/how-can-i-get-kendoui-mvc-to-work-with-content-security-policy but 'unsafe-eval' is not avoidable: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/troubleshoot/content-security-policy Kendo uses eval() calls

Answer (score -1):

#### For Chrome Manifest 3 you can add

```json
{
  "content_security_policy":{
  "extension_page": "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'" ,
  "sandbox": "extension_page": "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'" ,
  }               
}
```